# How to create a .deb file with dependency?

Tags: dependencies, packaging

I have a game made with the LÖVE framework and I want to package it into a `.deb` file so it can be easily installed by others and be easily findable through the Unity dash for example.

I also have the LÖVE framework `love_0.7.2.deb` which I want to be in the deb file also somehow.

Files that I have:

```
game_icon.png
game .desktop
the_game.love
love_0.7.2.deb
```

Could someone explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 12):

In order to make one package depend on another, you need to specify the relationship in the `debian/control` file. You can [read about the syntax of this file in the Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/debian-dir-overview.html#the-control-file). The rest of that guide will probably be helpful in giving you an overview of packaging programs for Ubuntu.

Briefly though, your `debian/control` file might look something like:

```
Source: my-game
Section: devel
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Jane Doe <packager@example.com>
Standards-Version: 3.9.3
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7)
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/

Package: my-game
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, love (>= 0.7.2)
Description: a game made with the LÖVE framework
 This game is really amazing.
 .
 It has many features.
```

Especially note the line:

> Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, **love (>= 0.7.2)**

Comment: I have never created a deb file before. I have created this now http://www.speedyshare.com/3qhHQ/not-pacman.tar.gz . Does that look right? if so how do i make it into a deb file?

Comment: @Jeggy Start out by the packaging guide already suggested. If you have a specific question, please ask a new question. Also, packaging isn't always a very easy task and is a job on its own. Very "simple to compile" applications are generally easy to package as well (e.g. `./confgure && make && make install` ones using GNU Autotools) are pretty easy, though. Debhelper has a lot of heuristic in these very generic cases.

Comment: See also: "Declaring relationships between packages" in the Debian Policy Manual.
(https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html)