# How do I make a debian package install or upgrade other packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I'm using Ubuntu in my work and I have just created a small `.deb` package to make some configs in my system. I need this package to install or upgrade some other packages, so I put some installing commands in the `postinst` script, but installation exits with an error telling me there is another package manager already running.

How can I make my `.deb` package install or upgrade other packages as part of its installation process?

Comment: That's what dependencies are for.

Comment: How to add a dependency: https://askubuntu.com/questions/240421/how-to-create-a-deb-file-with-dependency